# CheckSpelling On gives XAMPP Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

Apache error.log:

```
[Sat Feb 23 02:19:46.233604 2013] [core:alert] [pid 6904:tid 1592] [client ::1:53186] C:/xampp/htdocs/me/.htaccess: Invalid command 'CheckCaseOnly', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/me/
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

CheckCaseOnly On
CheckSpelling On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ /me/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /me/index.php?unikpage=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is giving a server error. I trying to make the URLs case sensitive. How is it done?

Comment: `mod_speling` is enabled in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: Is `mod_speling.so` in the `/modules` directory?

Comment: Thanks. the mod was commented out@ I jsut learned '#' means comments.
I changed:
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
To:
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so

The problem is, it is still not case sensitive. Yes, I did restart apache after saving it.

Comment: How do you know is not working, how are you testing it? What are you trying to use it for, just to detect case changes?

Comment: @faa how can one add `mod_speling.so` to the `/modules` directory if it is not in there?  Is this something I can DL from somewhere and just plop into there, or is it a more complicated installation?

Comment: You can download the complete server release [here](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache22). Maybe also the single module but don't know where. Be aware [mod_speling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html) have issues and you have to know what you are doing. To install it, just copy the file to the `/modules` directory and restart the server.